# Why io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable asMaps(String.class, String.class).get(0) returns Map<Object,Object> and not Map<String,String>

Tags: java, cucumber

if I parse `io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable` I encountered following problem:
I have `dataTable` (io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable) as a parameter in method.

I try to convert it to List of Maps by `dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class)`.
Even though I specify type **String.class** for key and value, the Maps are created as Map<**Object**,**Object**>.

So I cannot use it directly e.g. in stream:

```
dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class).stream()
                .forEach(row -> Boolean.parseBoolean(row.get("enabled")));
```

[See an error shown by Intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkhVy.png)

But first I must store it in variable:

```
List<Map<String, String>> rows = dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
// BTW, this seems to be sufficient: List<Map<String, String>> rows = dataTable.asMaps();
rows.stream().forEach(row -> Boolean.parseBoolean(row.get("enabled")));
```

Why there are those parameters (**String.class**, **String.class**) if they are not taken into account?

Comment: What leads you to beleive they're created as `Map<Object, Object>`? What exactly goes wrong in your first example?

Comment: @OhleC [See an error shown by Intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkhVy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are used to look up a conversion for your data into the required type. The signature is

```java
public <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> asMaps(Type keyType, Type valueType)
```

Since the argument types are not parameterized, the compiler can't infer `K` and `V` from your call.

I also found [this javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber/api/DataTable.html#) which got me confused because with the signature there it *would* work:

```java
public <K,V> List<Map<K,V>> asMaps(Class<K> keyType,
                                   Class<V> valueType)
```

This would let the compiler infer the map key- and value types as String. I have no idea what version of cucumber that documentation refers to.

However, with both there is also a specific String version: `asMaps()` without any arguments should always return a `List<Map<String, String>>` so should at least cover your case.

Comment: Thanks @OhleC. BTW I am using https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/datatable/3.4.0/io/cucumber/datatable/DataTable.html

Comment: I found that since [cucumber-jvm 3.0.0](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v3.0.0.md) the DataTable was moved from `cucumber.api.DataTable` to `io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable`.
With this migration also the signature was changed to `<K,V> List<Map<K,V>> asMaps(Type keyType, Type valueType)` and new one is provided `List<Map<String,String>> asMaps()` as you already suggested.